# Windows 10 clock shows misordered day and weekday

Tags: windows-10, date

I use the calendar a lot for my job.

Since I have Windows 10, I've been lost with the calendar because it shows days in a different position than the correct date.

Let's say today is Monday 7, it shows on Monday the number 6, which is wrong.

The days of the week are on day in Advanced.

I completely checked the settings of date and time, and everything is in order.

I also searched on Google, but I didn't find an answer for my problem.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you´re from Venezuela like me, this issue only happens when your time zone is set to Caracas GMT-4:30.

If you remove the entry `Dynamic DST` in Windows Registry the issue will be solved after your next Windows restart.

The entry is  located in

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE » SOFTWARE » Microsoft » Windows NT » CurrentVersion » Time Zones » Venezuela Standard Time`.

If you want, you can create a empty text file with any name but with `.reg` extension and copy the following line to it.

> `[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Venezuela Standard Time\Dynamic DST]`

After that double click your file and the entry will be removed... 
and your issue fixed after your next Windows restart.

Answer (score 0):

I solved or fixed the same problem on my PC (Windows time and date tray icon displaying the wrong day of the week; Calendar too exactly as the screen shot in the question, one day ahead.  This problem carried through to my G-mail; I would send and receive emails today but both e-mails were noted as "sent yesterday".  I was getting tomorrow's news today!  After solution my G-mail now shows correct days.)

Note: I cannot re-create the problem, and it has not occurred again.

**Solution: From the desktop, go to the time and date tray, open it to calendar, and open the calendar's time and date settings. Select the "Internet Time" tab. Now "Change settings" and then click "Update now".**

**BTW** "time.windows.com" was showing and I let it be. Just curious; has my hero Bill Gates been getting tomorrow's news today?